# Rename columns with filenames while merging many tables in R using Reduce

Tags: r, merge, reduce, read.table

I read all my files like this:

```
tables <- lapply(files, function(x) read.table(x, col.names=c("unit","count")))
```

and I am later going to merge them using column `unit`. However, I wish that instead of `count`, I could use original filename from variable `files` as a second column. That's because I am later performing merging like this:

```
MyMerge <- function(x, y){
  df <- merge(x, y, by="unit", all.x= TRUE, all.y= TRUE)
  return(df)
}

data <- Reduce(MyMerge, tables)
```

which causes problems since `merge` function cannot handle more that 3 non-unique column names (those become count.x, count.y and count so my script cannot handle more than 3 files).

Comment: Is it not just enough to do col.names = c('unit', x) ?? This will read the files in with first colum unit and second column the name of the file

Comment: It absolutely is!! Thank you. If you add this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as easy as doing:

```
tables <- lapply(files, function(x) read.table(x, col.names=c("unit", x)))
```

Maybe you also want to clean a bit the file name before to add it as column name something like:

```
col.names=c("unit", gsub('\\.csv', '', x))
```

In case you want to remove the .csv from the coulmn name or something similar